# Theme.Compat, ActionBar, Fragments, and support libraries

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an existing app with a minSdk of 14, now targeting 21, and I would like to use Theme.AppCompat to get the "Material look" throughout. This app also uses ActionBar tabs and ViewPager (FragmentPagerAdapter, etc.). I was previously using the native ActionBar and Fragment classes, but in order to use AppCompat from support.v7 it looks like I also have to use support.v7.app.ActionBar and related classes.

The issue I then ran into is that some support library ActionBar classes, such as the ActionBar.TabListener abstract interface, define methods that require the *support library* version of Fragments (support.v4.app.Fragment, et al). So now I'm faced with extensive modifications throughout the app to import the support library classes, change to getSupportFragmentManager, etc.

Is this the only route I can take for using the AppCompat themes for V14-21 -- switch entirely to the support library for both the action bar and fragments? Do some of these classes pass thru to the native classes at execution time?

Comment: either that or set your min API to `21` but I doubt you want to do that

Comment: i guess I'll have to do the complete conversion then. Of course, it's not like I'm surprised at something taking about 5x the time of what I originally estimated it would take!